# Dialer that shows nickname instead of Firstname Lastname

Tags: contacts, phone-app

I am desperately looking for a way that would show **Mom** instead of **Jane Doe** when I receive a call. Right now, *Google Contacts* app allows to search by word *mom* but it's not shown in Dialer/SMS/WhatsApp etc

**UPD**: I was advised [True Phone Dialer & Contacts & Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hb.dialer.free) but I don't see much configurable settings for the requested feature

[image]